# Java JTable Date Formatting Issues

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Hey all so I am working on designing a GUI that will show a JTable (populated directly from my Database (Oracle) using SQL statements to Select X tables) and then have a bunch of sorting functions for the table, etc.

One thing I would like is a Date range specifier. So if I have a table like so:

```
 File |   Date 
------|-------
   01 | 01-FEB-15
   02 | 02-FEB-15
   03 | 03-FEB-15
   04 | 01-MAR-15
   05 | 01-APR-15
```

I have 2 textboxes for the user to enter a beginning date and end date and then the table will update to show only files that have a Date that falls within the range.

The column in my DB is of type Date, and I did not change it from default so it should be of format: `'YYYY-MM-DD'`

I am using JDBC to connect to my DB through Java App and pass SQL queries to the DB however I keep getting errors when trying to achieve this date range.

Some code I have written to try and accomplish this task:

```
JButton btnFetchDates = new JButton("Fetch");
    btnFetchDates.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String start = "2015.02.01";
            String end = "2015.03.01";
            String pattern = "yyyy.MM.dd";
            if (comboBoxUsers.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Bob")){
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
                    java.util.Date startD = sdf.parse(start);
                    java.util.Date endD = sdf.parse(end);
                    String query1 = "SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE USER_ID = 1 AND FILE_DATE > " + "'" + startD + "'" + " AND FILE_DATE < " + "'" + endD + "';";
                    pat = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
                    rs = pat.executeQuery();
                    tableData.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
        }
    });
```

However this just gives me error: `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` but nothing appears to be wrong with the SQL query String. I get the feeling that I am not using the Date Formatter correctly or perhaps there is a much easier way to go about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use placeholders (eg a question mark in the query) of the [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), setting the date values via its setX methods (where X is the date type of the placeholder):

```
String query1 = "SELECT * FROM FILES WHERE USER_ID = 1 AND FILE_DATE > ? AND FILE_DATE < ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query1);
ps.setDate(1, startD);
ps.setDate(2, endD);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Note that a) the setDate accepts a java.sql.Date object (which extends java.util.Date) b) depending upon the column date type in the database, you may need to do a conversion of type in the query (to date) or java side (use another setX method - eg setTimestamp).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I know this code is really bad, I am just trying to get some sort of output and then go back and tighten everything up.